# Use python's webbrowser module to click links

Tags: python, module, click, browser, hyperlink

I'd like to make python click specific links based on the url that I put in:

```
webbrowser.open('www.website.com.')
```

To accomplish this, I was thinking of using BeautifulSoup to gather the urls in the html that start with 'website.com' and putting that in a:

```
webbroswer.open_new_tab('www.website.com/next_link')
```

However, ideally, I'd like to simulate an actual click on these links.

Is this possible?

Edit: From what I understand about Selenium, I would need to make a recording of what actions I would like performed on the website: clicking links and staying on those pages for a certain amount of time. As I said above, the functionality I want is for my browser to click links based on the original url that I put into my program. I would also like my browser to stay on a tab for a random amount of time between 30 seconds and 1 minute. Is selenium able to do these things? Or would I have to make a different recording for each website?

Comment: Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org) is your answer.

Comment: Have you tried [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)? It does pretty much what you describe.